# Elementary Calendar doesn't sync with owncloud 10.0.10

Tags: release-juno, calendar

Hi there i tried the sync my calendar with my own owcloud (caldav).
I get no data from the calendar, but i can set up new events which are updated to my owncloud calendar. 
So it seems working only one way.
Any suggestions ? If you want i can add some logs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post your issue [here](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues) :-)

EDIT: Sorry @Hasan you are right, of course! For better clarification why I post this link and to give a more valuable answer here comes an explanation.

A fail of sync can have many reasons. In this case it maybe is a problem of the client (which in this case is the elementary calendar app), because I can sync my owncloud (10.1.0) with thunderbird lightning and I hadn't any problems beforehand. Still it can be an issue of your server configuration though. However, I am not an expert in this so thats why I posted the link above.

The link I posted above will redirect you the offical github repository of the elementary calendar app. The Github repository holds the open source code of the app and provides an issue tracker. Posting an issue there is a great help for developers, especially when a user can provide a log.

For posting an issue in an elementary repository there are some things you can do things easier for everyone:

- First check if there is a similar or even the same issue already posted
- If so you can give a thumb up in the error description to mark that you have exactly the same issue [image]
- Add valuable information, maybe an additional description which also triggers the issue, provide logs
- If not: Try to provide a description that makes it easy for devs to recreate the problem, provide logs and a system configuration.
- Be nice and patient :-)

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated. Please do vote to close a question which you believe is because of bug or is a feature request. Because such question can not be solved over Q&A.